# Should I make up Eid prayer after quietly laughing?

Tags: salat, eid, laughter

During the Eid prayer I laughed because of something a little girl did. It was a very quiet laugh. Do you know if I have to make this prayer up? Should I make it up at home?

Comment: There is no make up for Eid prayer.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I made research and knows, the Salah o Eid-Fitr is considered as a Wajib (obligatory) Salah from the viewpoint of Sunni brothers (by its conditions…), although it is not counted as a Wajib practice from the viewpoint of Shiite, haply Shiite consider it as a Mustahab or recommended Salah.

On the other hand, regarding laughing during Salah, (I'm not sure concerning the perspective of Sunni, but on the whole, from the perspective of Shia, laughing loudly would invalidate the Salah, but laughing slowly (not loudly) doesn't seem to invalidate it. (Beside, being advertently or inadvertently would be effective in it as well)

**Conclusion:**

Apparently it is not necessary to make it up as @Ozbak (as a Sunni brother) mentioned it as well.

---

**References:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa9406)
- [porseman.mihanblog.com](http://porseman.mihanblog.com/post/115)
- [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/2792)
- [mazhabetasannon.vcp.ir](http://[http://mazhabetasannon.vcp.ir/359772-][4])

Comment: _the Salah o Eid-Fitr is considered as a Wajib Salah from the viewpoint of Sunni brothers_ → Eid prayer is wajib only in Hanafi school of fiqh and as fiqh terms there is a difference between fard and wajib (again only in Hanafi). The other 3 Sunni schools of fiqh consider Eid prayer as sunnah prayer.